# How to get "Web audio spatialization" to work

Tags: javascript, websocket, html5-audio, web-audio-api, communication

I am trying to move the position of a media source when it gets a position update to allow for proximity voice chat.

right now all the voices are at a constant volume no matter where the panner or listner are set in the world

https://gist.github.com/DrMeepso/127ee76ea62581fcf517464e58c58f59
At case 21 of the websocket player postions are stored as vector6
X, Y, Z: position and A, B, C: rotation

I've tryed all diffrent types of syntax and i just cant seem to get it to work. any help would be apresheated

Comment: Are you using headphones? The Web Audio API's spatialization works only with headphones.

Comment: Yes i am using headphones